# How do I search nested objects for a specific property value and return an ancestor element?

Tags: javascript, dom, devtools

I want a function to return an element based on what the value of a child element's property is. How do I traverse HTMLCollections to do this?

[image: Here is the element with the property I'm trying to find]

This is the object that I'm beginning with.

```
HTMLCollection { 0: colgroup.Table__Colgroup, 1: thead.Table__header-group.Table__THEAD, 2: tbody.Table__TBODY}
```

​

```
function readValuesIn(prop) {
    prprt = prop.innerText;  // desired value
    for (prop in yearColumns) {   // runs through nesting properties
      if (prprt.includes("NO")) { // searches for "NO"
       prop.indexOf(prop.closest(tr)) // returns row number (tr element) of NO's first instance
       } else { 
         readValuesIn(prop[i]) // iterates over nesting  child array and repeats test
        }
     }    
    }


function readValuesOf(prop) {
        prprt = prop.innerText; // desired value
        for (prop of yearColumns) {   // runs through nesting properties
          if (prprt.includes("NO")) { // searches for "NO"
           prop.indexOf(prop.closest(tr)) // returns row number of NO's first instance
           } else { 
             readValuesOf(Array.from(prop[i])) // convert HTMLCollection to array and perform recursion
            }
         }  
        }
```

Comment: What have you attempted to achieve this? That will give us some better context.

Comment: I started with `Array.from()` to use methods like `find()` `includes()` `indexOf()` and `closest()` within various for loops (`for-in`, `for-of`) and conditions. I've also tried iterating over `Object.hasOwn()` `Object.keys` `Object.values`. I can't seem to get the console in Firefox Developer Edition to return an object other than what I start with though.. @mykaf

Comment: Please add your attempts to your original post.

Comment: When/how do you call `readValuesIn()`? What does the original HTML look like?

Comment: I call `readValuesIn()` in the console after the function. I'll update the HTML above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, essentially a mutli-dimensional array has various avenues to a final object - (is the situation I'm working with). Say you want the value (in this case index) of an object that's about halfway down the array's dimensions AND, THAT object depends on a property of the final dimension of the array. Slingshot to the final dimension to verify you have the correct avenue. Then, in order to get the index, repel down the children of an ancestor element leveraging properties and functions of `array.from()` `.length` & `.indexOf()`.

```js
    // DEEP SEEDED DESCENDENT PROPERTY INDICATES AVENUE TO DESIRED OBJECT
fleurDeLis = document.querySelector('img[Title=NO]');

// OVERSHOOT DESIRED ASCENDENT TO REPELL FROM HIGHER ASCENDENT'S ARRAY OF CHILDREN
column = Array.from(fleurDeLis.closest('table').rows);

// REPELL FROM HIGHER ASCENDENT TO DESIRED OBJECT'S VALUE
saintsRow = column.indexOf(fleurDeLis.closest('tr'));
```